# Emulate picture in picture mode in Android

Tags: android, responsive-design, picture-in-picture, android-picture-in-picture

I am making a highly responsive app and I'd b interested in seeing what it looks like basically at any arbitrary size. I have a Samsung Tab A tablet that has picture in picture mode for all apps, and I can resize, so I can see what my app looks like at any size.

My collaborators don't have access to these tablets, so I am wondering how could they emulate this? Either emulate a Samsung Tab A that has this capability, or emulate something tht has the same kind of picture in picture.

Thanks